# How to fix 'TypeError: 'module' object is not callable'

Tags: python

I am new to python

My folder structure is

main->abc

inside abc folder i have created a class abc with filename abc.py

abc.py

```
class abc:
      x=""
      def __init__(self,y):
         self.x=y
```

inside main i created a file test.py

test.py

```
from abc import abc

a=abc("test")
```

but i am getting error `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`

i tried creating __init__.py inside folder abc 
but still same error

How to do modules if i have same folder names?

in lot of packages i have saw same names

Comment: Have you tried "from abc.abc import abc"?

Comment: @TechPerson thanks its working fine

Comment: Don't name your module `abc` for the love of god( Sorry for exagerating :) ). Please check the stdlib module names before you name user modules, because this will conflict with the `stdlib` module `abc` in  `'/usr/lib/python2.7/abc.pyc'`

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @TechPerson

`from abc.abc import abc`